# What is this type of HTTP format?

Tags: http, charles-proxy, sniffing

I am doing some experiments with Charles proxy, and I spotted an HTTP request that looks like this:

```
:method: POST
:path: /accounts/login/ajax/
:authority: www.instagram.com
:scheme: https
accept-encoding: deflate
accept-language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
origin: https://www.instagram.com
referer: https://www.instagram.com
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4
x-instagram-ajax: 1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
x-csrftoken: DYQiMZCtYEmxnSh4JOxPhXC2g7U3MT99
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
content-length: 33
cookie: rur=FRC; csrftoken=DYQiMZCtYEmxnSh4JOxPhXC2g7U3MT99; mid=WnCy2AAEAAGEdFpqRSkUCaeSSznE

username=blabla&password=blabla
```

As far as I know, standard HTTP request's first line should be something like `POST / HTTP/1.1`, but it's not.

And I don't understand why it has `:` in front of first 4 lines, and why it even has #2~4 lines.

Any info on this type of HTTP, or maybe something with Charles proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **HTTP2** request, and those lines with the semicolon are known as *pseudo-headers*.

Further reading: http://undertow.io/blog/2015/04/27/An-in-depth-overview-of-HTTP2.html#_request_response_overview

Comment: Oh, great thanks, I've never imagined HTTP2 header would look this retro in style... thought this should be coming from 90s.